# Can angular momentum directly be defined in terms of angular velocity?

Tags: angular-momentum, angular-velocity

I don't like it being defined as $\vec{r} \times \vec{mv}$ as the angular nature is not obvious in that definition.

Suppose there's a single particle moving around. We choose an arbitrary origin. We define the angular momentum at time $t$ as $m|\vec{r(t)}|^2$ times its angular velocity. Angular velocity at time $t$ is defined as the vector perpendicular to both $\vec{v(t)}$ and $\vec{r(t)}$ (according to some conventional rule), and having the magnitude $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$, where $\theta (t)$ is the angular position of the particle at time $t$ in the plane of $\vec{r(t)}$ and $\vec{v(t)}$, with respect to the chosen origin.

So this defines it for a single particle. For a system of particles, we just sum up the angular momenta. The formula $\vec{r}\times \vec{mv}$ is arrived at as a means of calculating it. Is this definition equivalent to $\vec{r}\times \vec{mv}$? Can either of these definitions be used for any general problem?

Comment: So your definition, for one particle, would be $\vec{p_{ang}}=m{|\vec r(t)|}^2\vec{\omega}$?

Comment: @descheleschilder yes

Comment: I can't see why not. Why do you think it wouldn't apply to a collection of particles? Or is this exactly what you ask?

Comment: @descheleschilder I was just making sure that it's the same thing and can be applied to all general problems.

Comment: You do realize that "perpendicular to both v and r" is exactly what the cross-product achieves right?

Comment: for me it seems you just try to explain the crossproduct, where r and  v are perpendicular ? try your approach for a planet moving on an ellipse.

Comment: @NDewolf I know. I was just trying to explicitly involve angular velocity in the definition. Something named angular momentum should be directly defined in terms of angular motion

Comment: @trula I don't think it's limited to just circular motion. For other motions, the angular velocity at an instant can still be defined in terms of the tangential component of the instantaneous linear velocity. That's what I'm trying to do in this approach.

Comment: your statement " the angular velocity at an instant can still be defined in terms of the tangential component of the instantaneous linear velocity." is not true, think for example at a linear movement with constant speed, the tangential velocity is the velocity itself, the radius to a fixed point increases, the angular moment is constant.

Comment: @trula Wouldn't the tangential velocity be decreasing in that case? The tangential velocity is the component of the velocity that is perpendicular to the position vector. As the particle moving with a constant velocity strays further from the chosen origin, its position vector becomes more and more lined up with its velocity, making the tangential component smaller and smaller.

Comment: your definition of tangential velocity is new. The common definition is: tangential to the curve, the point is traveling on, and only in circles the tangential velocity is p always perpendicular to the position vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the tangential velocity you can write $\vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r} $, substituting this in your expression you'll get the well-known expression for the angular momentum of a single particle: $\vec{L} = mr^2 \vec{\omega}$.
The quantity $mr^2$ is called the *moment of inertia* of a particle with respect to a certain axis of rotation. A generalisation can be made to a collection of particles, if they have fixed positions with respect to each other we say these particles consitute a *rigid body*. The general formula then becomes $\vec{L} = \bf{I} \vec{\omega}$ where $\bf{I}$ is called the *inertia tensor*.
Note that this has the same structure as in linear motion where $\vec{p} = m \vec{v}$ where in this case the mass $m$ takes the role of inertia.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I convinced myself that your formula is correct. I just calculated the crossproduct, and  put in omega instead of v. so your formula gives the right answer for th absolute value of p, but i still can not see why you do not see the change of angle in the cross product.

Comment: I'm not sure this is appropriate as an answer, since it is more a question than an answer.